# admob doesn't show ads in my app with ionic 5

Tags: ionic-framework, admob

I am having problems with Admob not showing ads in my ionic app 5.
Can someone help me I will share the code I used

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
import { AdMobFree, AdMobFreeBannerConfig, AdMobFreeInterstitialConfig, AdMobFreeRewardVideoConfig } from '@ionic-native/admob-free/ngx';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AdmobService {
  
  bannerConfig: AdMobFreeBannerConfig = {
    isTesting: false,
    autoShow: true,//,
    id: "ca-app-pub-************************"
    //id: "ID GENERATED AT ADMOB ca-app-pub FOR PROD"
    };
    
    //INTERSTITIAL CONFIG
    interstitialConfig: AdMobFreeInterstitialConfig = {
      isTesting: false,
    autoShow: false,
    id: "ca-app-pub-****************************",
    //id: "ID GENERATED AT ADMOB ca-app-pub FOR PROD"
    };
    //REWARD VIDEO CONFIG.
   
    //ADD PLATFORM Y ADMOB AT CONSTRUCTOR.
    constructor(
    public platform: Platform,
    private admobFree: AdMobFree
    ) {
    //LOAD ADS AT PLATFORM READY PROMISE.
    platform.ready().then(()=>{
    //BANNER
    this.admobFree.banner.config(this.bannerConfig);
    //INTERSTITIAL
    this.admobFree.interstitial.config(this.interstitialConfig);
    this.admobFree.interstitial.prepare().then(() => {
    console.log('INTERSTIAL LOADED')
    }).catch(e =>
    console.log('PROBLEM LOADING INTERSTITIAL: ', e)
    );
    //REWARD VIDEO
   
    
    
    
    
    
    });
    }
    ShowBanner() {
    //CHECK AND SHOW BANNER
    this.admobFree.banner.prepare().then(() => {
    console.log('BANNER LOADED')
    }).catch(e =>
    console.log('PROBLEM LOADING BANNER: ', e)
    );
    }
    ShowInterstitial() {
    //CHECK AND SHOW INTERSTITIAL
    this.admobFree.interstitial.isReady().then(() => {
    //AT .ISREADY SHOW 
    this.admobFree.interstitial.show().then(() => {
    console.log('INTERSTITIAL LOADED')
    })
    .catch(e => console.log('PROBLEM LOADING REWARD VIDEO: ', e)  );
    })
    .catch(e => console.log('PROBLEM LOADING REWARD VIDEO: ', e)  );
    }
    
    
    }
```

Comment: try the test ids first https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads.

Comment: i try the test ad works but the production ad does not work

Comment: Are you still looking for an answer?

Answer (score 0):

need the app to be published on google play for ads to appear?